# Lambda Join Group by where clause issue

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Why am I getting only one entry in `DownTimeDetails` list even though in Data we have 3 entries.

```
VehicleEventDetails Res = dbEntity.DownTimeHeaders
              .Join(dbEntity.DownTimeDetails, dth => dth.DownTimeHeaderID, dtd => dtd.DownTimeHeaderID, (dth, dtd) => new { dth, dtd })
              .Where(x => x.dth.DownTimeHeaderID == 42)
              .GroupBy(gx => gx.dtd.DownTimeDetailID)
              .Select(t => new VehicleEventDetails()
              {
                  BookingId = t.Select(a => a.dth.BookingId).FirstOrDefault(),
                  DownTimeDetails = t.Select(ab => new DownTimeDetails
                  {
                      LocalDTStartTime = (DateTime)ab.dtd.LocalDTStartTime,
                      LocalDTEndTime = (DateTime)ab.dtd.LocalDTEndTime,
                      CalculatedEventDTReason = ab.dtd.CalculatedEventDTReason,
                      CalculatedEventDTInMinutes = (int)ab.dtd.CalculatedEventDT,
                  }).ToList()
              }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: @NetMage It is property of Class VehicleEventDetails . It is List<DownTimeDetails>

Comment: Can you provide some sample data?

Comment: I suspect the problem is you're expecting multiple DownTimeDetails.. but grouping on DownTimeDetailID instead of the DownTimeHeaderID. Grouping on the DetailID will always bring back one.

Comment: I need to get resultset of DowntimeHeaderID==42 from table DownTimeDetails as well as from table DownTimeHeaders. But results from table DownTimeDetails should come into List.

Comment: @Cory Thanks.. I got issue now..Fixed this.. Thanks you so much !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for something like this:

```
VehicleEventDetails Res = dbEntity.DownTimeHeaders
    .Where(x => x.DownTimeHeaderID == 42)
    .Select(x => new VehicleEventDetails
    {
        BookingId = x.BookingId,
        DownTimeDetails = x.DownTimeDetails
            .Select(dtd=> new DownTimeDetails
            {
                LocalDTStartTime = (DateTime)dtd.LocalDTStartTime,
                LocalDTEndTime = (DateTime)dtd.LocalDTEndTime,
                CalculatedEventDTReason = dtd.CalculatedEventDTReason,
                CalculatedEventDTInMinutes = (int)dtd.CalculatedEventDT,
            })
            .ToList()
    })
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Notes:

- Using `.Join` is an anti-Entity Framework pattern. Always try to use navigation properties, they exist for a reason.
- Don't use `.GroupBy` unless you actually need a group. You don't want any grouping in this query.
- As a general note, try not to make the expression variable names so confusing.

Comment: DownTimeDetails = x.DownTimeDetails , X will not have property

Comment: @NitinJain Because you didn't create a navigational property, because you are not using Entity Framework correctly. Just add a `public virtual ICollection<DownTimeDetails> DownTimeDetails { get; set; }` to the DownTimeHeaders class

Comment: @NitinJain Please do not edit my answer to use your code. Your code is wrong and you should change it.

Comment: Sorry, Thanks for correcting me for best practices also.